# How to load different configs for MoxieManager

Tags: moxiemanager

I use Moxiemanager as a standalone plugin (just including `moxman.loader.min.js`).

This file calls `api.php`, where `MOXMAN` class initialises with default `config.php` file.

```
// Load default config
if (!isset($moxieManagerConfig)) {
    $moxieManagerConfig = array();
    require_once(MOXMAN_ROOT . '/config.php');
}
```

What would be the best way to pick different configs for different pages?

For example on 1 page i would like to change autoformat rules and on another change folder path.

Can i pass a parameter somehow? Or define a constant?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i found that the easiest way would be just to have a separate folder for images with `mc_access` file where we can redefine the settings.

- Create a folder
- Set `rootpath` to this folder in `js`
- Put `ms_access` file with redefined settings.

Comment: How do you set the rootpath in JS?

Comment: rootpath is one of the options you can pass to `.browse()` method.
Here is the documentation https://www.moxiemanager.com/documentation/index.php/js_browse

So you will call it like 

`moxman.browse({rootpath: 'PATH', ...});`